# Formal word for 'emit anal air'?

Tags: single-word-requests, formality, offensive-language, minced-oaths

Is there a formal single word for 'emit anal air'? I've heard 'eructate' being used, but this means air from the mouth only; not from the other end.

Comment: Look up 'flatulate'.

Comment: Words can have spaces in them, like *break wind* or *pass gas*.  Not that those are “formal”.   One does not speak of these matters ***at all*** [in the most formal of settings](http://urbanlegends.about.com/library/bl_gw_queen.htm), where [they are taboo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fart). Therefore no formal word will be found. For that matter, *anal* is probably also best left unsaid there — you perhaps mean “from one’s backside”.

Comment: Perhaps "technical" would be a better descriptor than "formal".  As in "How would this phenomenon be identified in an academic paper?"

Comment: @tchrist: No, those are phrases. Not a (single) word.

Answer (score 10):

[Flatulence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatulence): [the presence of too much gas or air in the stomach or intestines](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flatulence).

The action would be [flatulate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flatulate): To emit digestive gases from the anus, especially with accompanying sound.

[Fart](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fart) is the slang form.

---

After long hours of scouring the etymology of 'noisy bowels', I came across this gem.

**[Borborygm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatulence):** The noise made by gas in the bowels.

Thought I'd share in my discovery.

Comment: Good answer. A somewhat less slang term would be to "break wind".

Comment: Is fart slang for flatulate? I thought fart was a much older term and probably not really slang at all, until the Victorians got a whiff of it.

Comment: _Fart_ is in fact the English form. Anybody who says _flatulate_ will be taken as having attempted a joke. And failed, probably. The formal term is 'wind from the bowels'; Benjamin Franklin wrote a treatise on this subject.

Comment: @JohnLawler In the [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flatulate) link, it lists Fart as a slang term. It may be older, but most of the fun words are. Also, I believe most medical people will say: "Do you feel flatulent?" for gassy feelings. It might not be very common, but I have come across this before especially in countries that speak English as a common second language (Philippines, India, etc).

Comment: No, *fart* is clearly not “slang”, which is as defined as one of: (a) The special vocabulary used by any set of persons of a low or disreputable character; language of a low and vulgar type. (b) The special vocabulary or phraseology of a particular calling or profession; the cant or jargon of a certain class or period. (c)  Language of a highly colloquial type, considered as below the level of standard educated speech, and consisting either of new words or of current words employed in some special sense.

Comment: Um, Wiktionary is not a reliable source for technical terms like "slang", since absolutely anybody, with any, or no, knowledge of the language can contribute. It's good for collecting general meanings, but terrible for sociolinguistics, like any general dictionary.

Comment: @JohnLawler Fine. Wiktionary no, but [Dictionary of American Slang and Colloquial Expressions by Richard A. Spears.Fourth Edition. 
Copyright 2007. Published by McGraw-Hill Education.](http://www.amazon.com/McGraw-Hills-Dictionary-American-Colloquial-Expressions/dp/0071461078) should be acceptable, right? On a side note, it did have this note: "(Often objectionable. One of the classic four-letter words. It should be noted that English does not have a single, “polite” word, noun or verb, for this matter. Break wind is common, but there is no parallel noun...)".

Comment: Didn't say it wasn't rude. But it's not slang. It's the ordinary word, taboo and all. Slang is ephemeral and goes "23 Skidoo" very fast, while taboo words are the oldest and healthiest words in the language, because everybody has to know what they are in order not to use them.

Comment: @JohnLawler Personally, I still think 'rude' is wrong. Why should words that describe something so perfectly be considered rude and vulgar. If you were to say, "Holy shit! Someone farted!" I would instantly understand what you mean immediately and brace myself for the incoming storm. If you said, "Goodness! Someone passed gas from his buttocks!" I would probably be unable to process what you said in time. I think that these words should be used more often so their taboo status gets dropped.

Comment: I must of course agree. See [Carlin 1972](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lqvLTJfYnik) on the subject, for instance.

Comment: @JohnLawler Haha! I, too, am a [Carlinist](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Carlinism).

Comment: Thanks for yor suggestions. So the options are 'break wind'; 'flatulate', which is an improper back-formed word; or 'fart' which is currently informal.